# PHP AES128Decryption

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I used [this Class](https://github.com/tharindu/AES128Encryption-ObjC) to encrypt a NSString. I now need a PHP script to decrypt it again. How do I do that? Already tried this:

```
echo mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "hi", base64_decode("XzFXgmIZmPF04CJDlUQ0eIoe47BUXTj3Am+86+QFo6A="),MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
```

but it does not return anything.

Comment: Have you tried encrypting the cleartext string + base64 encoding the result in PHP to ensure that it matches the `"XzFX..."` string above?

Comment: no, but that is not the point. the php one has to be adjusted to the iOS one.

Answer (score 0):

solved it, had to install mcrypt....